# How to replace HTMLLoader to display PDF inside air application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

With the latest version of adobe air the component HTMLLoader has been removing.
In my case, I used it to display pdf files inside my air application.

```
if ( HTMLLoader.pdfCapability == HTMLPDFCapability.STATUS_OK )
{
if ( dgHisto.selectedIndex != -1 )
{
var urlCourTXT:String=dgHisto.selectedItem.courl;
container.removeAllChildren();
urlCourTXTServ=new urlManager().urlCourriers() + urlCourTXT;//+ "#statusbar=0";

        pdf.height=container.height-10;
        pdf.width=container.width-10;
        
        
        var request:URLRequest=new URLRequest( urlCourTXTServ );
       
        try
        {
            pdf.load( request );
        }
        catch (error:ArgumentError)
        {
            Alert.show( "An ArgumentError has occurred : error:ArgumentError" , "Attention", Alert.OK, this);
            
        }
        catch (error:SecurityError)
        {
            Alert.show( " error:SecurityError" , "Alert", Alert.OK, this);
        }
          
        var ui:UIComponent=new UIComponent();
        ui.addChild( pdf );
        container.addChild( ui );
    }
    
}
```

In this sample, container is a mx:VBox with drag and drop event.
So I try to do the same with StageWebView but it doesn't work !

```
package fr.mycompagny.component.pdf
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.media.StageWebView;
    
    import spark.components.BorderContainer;

    public class WebView extends BorderContainer
    {
        private var _webView : StageWebView;
        public function WebView()
        {
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            
            _webView.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE,onAddedToStage);
        }
        
        
        private function onAddedToStage(event : Event) : void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE,onAddedToStage);
            
            createWebView();
            
            _webView.loadURL("http://www.sitename/pdfName.pdf");
        }
        
        private function createWebView() : void
        {
            _webView          = new StageWebView();
            _webView.stage    = stage;
            _webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0,
                0,
                stage.stageWidth,
                stage.stageHeight);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Could you help me to find a solution.
Thanks for helping.
Best regards

Comment: _"I try to do the same with StageWebView but it doesn't work"_ Your code is not using any StageWebView so we can't fix any possible mistakes. See if [this example code](https://community.adobe.com/t5/animate-discussions/load-pdf-file-inside-the-application-android-and-ipad/m-p/5406851#M139535) works for you.

Comment: I try to create a new component to display PDF and include it on a box (container).

Comment: First check the file is loadable/readable... Does [using NavigateToURL to load the PDF](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7cba.html) work to display it?

Comment: Yes with ##var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlCourTXTServ); and navigateToURL(urlReq);##  the file is opening in the web browser. But in my case, in need to open it on my air application. Thanks

Comment: Anyone to help me ? Many thanks in advance. Best regards

Comment: I don't think there is any free options in 2022 to use PDF in AIR. It's a shame because Adobe makes PDF and Adobe makes AIR but the two things don't work together. You have two options **(1)** Pay for [an existing solution](https://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.PDFReader) **(2)** Create your own PDF Reader code. Depends how complicated the PDF you display. If just text and image, consider opening the PDF in a **hex editor** and using the internet to find out what each section means (from there you extract the text/images and display each page content inside a Sprite object).